# How can I create custom packages with some classes like the android.app package

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I create custom packages with some classes like the android.app package or etc. 
For example all the standard packages are in the `Android.jar` file. Is this possible for us to create something like the `Android.jar` file on side this `Android.jar` and using them together? I have **Android studio 1.3**.

Comment: Better to create your own `Module` and used any where or in any app

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking to do is create a `Library Project`. To do that in Android Studio go to File > New Module > Android Library.

Here's a useful [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/daniellevass/2c46cf33e3814e685b47) to teach you how to use the Library in other projects.